# latexmk calls maketfm

Tags: latexmk

consider this file

```latex
\documentclass{scrreport}

\usepackage[activate = true]{microtype}

\begin{document}

Hi

\end{document}
```

If I compile this file using `pdflatex test.tex` no errors occur, and I get a fully functional pdf file.

However, if I switch to `latexmk test`, it tries to make a font(?):

```
(C:\Users\lenni\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\mt-cmr.cfg)Running miktex-makemf.exe...

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\lenni\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log
Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
Couldn't open `cmr10+.cfg'

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)


Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\lenni\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log

! Font csnameendcsname=cmr10+20 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
found.
<to be read again>
                   relax
l.5 \begin{document}

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on doku.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'doku.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'doku.fls'
PWD line not in UTF-8
Latexmk: Examining 'doku.log'
Latexmk: Log file says no output from latex
Latexmk: For rule 'latex', no output was made
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  latex: Command for 'latex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'doku.log' for details
Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (437,65001)
```

And I don't get any pdf output.

What is happening here? How can I stop `latexmk` from generating unnecessary fonts?

Comment: use `latexmk -pdf test`. Without the `-pdf` you are trying to create a dvi and that doesn't work well with microtype.

Answer (score 1):

Ulrike Fischer's comment fixed my issue. I was also able to save the -pdf option in a local latexmkrc like this:

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
```